# Preciso compilar o vue para poder ver as alterações de estilo que fiz?

Tags: vue.js

Estou usando o VUE JS pela primeira vez.

Baixei todas as dependências através do npm, inclusive o próprio VUE.

Estou com as seguintes dúvidas:

- Para poder visualizar as alterações no css preciso fazer um build?
- Como importo uma biblioteca de css através do vue?

Comment: Estou. Há alguma diferença dele para o VUE JS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1 -** Não, não precisa fazer build, build é para quando sua aplicação estiver pronta e você quer os arquivos para enviar para produção, pode ler mais sobre [aqui](https://vuejs-brasil.com.br/separando-codigo-vue/). Para você rodar o projeto e visualizar suas alterações dê o seguinte comando no prompt: **`npm run dev`**, após este comando e se os arquivos não contiverem erros, sua aplicação estará apta para ser visualizada digitando em qualquer browser de sua preferência o seguinte endereço **`localhost:8080`**, para saber mais leia [aqui](https://medium.com/trainingcenter/criando-um-projeto-vuejs-com-o-vuecli-e-webstorm-58b695339c01).

**2 -** Para você instalar qualquer biblioteca, framework ou qualquer outro tipo de dependência no projeto você pode instalar através de comando no prompt, por exemplo, instalar o **bootstrap**, execute o seguinte comando: **`npm install bootstrap`** e importa-lo geralmente no arquivo `index.js` na pasta **router** para poder ficar disponível em toda a aplicação com o seguinte comando: **import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap'** e import **'bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css'** para poder utilizar o CSS do Bootstrap, mais o comando: **Vue.use(Bootstrap)**, ficando algo parecido com isto:

```
import Bootstrap from 'bootstrap'
import 'bootstrap/dist/bootstrap.min.css'

Vue.use(Bootstrap)
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, entendi perfeitamente.

Comment: No entanto, me referi a um estilo, na verdade. Se eu quiser importar um folha de estilo própria, como devo fazer? Quando declaro o estilo no <head>, não funciona.

Comment: Não, você não tem que importar, você escreve o css no arquivo mesmo. Como está utilizando vue-cli os arquivos ficam com a extensão **.vue**, este arquivo é dividido em três partes, **template** que é o HTML, **script** que é o JS e o **style** que é o CSS, pode escrever o seus estilos ali dentro destas tags.